# Intellij 'Go to symbol' shortcut in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, shortcut

There is a shortcut in IntelliJ I'm looking equivalent in Eclipse, it is called 'Go to symbol'. CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-N lets you start typing and glob up classes, method names, variable names, etc, from the entire project.

Does someone know if there is such thing in eclipse?

Comment: funny I was looking for the opposite, i.e. I knew the shortcut in Eclipse but not in IntelliJ... yet your question between being detailed enough helped me anyway :-)

Comment: Is there such a shortcut for Eclipse?

Comment: well yeah... that was your question wasn't it? and the answer is.. well the one you accepted

Comment: Yes, exactly haha anyway the solution isn't a total replacement for the IntelliJ shortcut that allows you to search for methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685467/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-goto-function-name

Comment: [open element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189481) is much closer to what was asked IMO. Proposed alternatives (e.g. go to definition) are often more useful, but they are not what was asked. The dialog of "open element" is still useful to find something that is not in any editor ATM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### General

For type names, you can use control-shift-t (open type) and enter partial names with globs or by upper letters in the camel-case name (like DTM for DefaultTableModel).

For resources (non java files like xml, properties, etc), you can use <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>

For method and variable names, you'd need to use the Java Search function (the flashlight icon on the toolbar).

### In the Java editor

If you're looking for references to a symbol in the editor, click on it and press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>.

If you're looking for the definition of a symbol in the editor, control-click or click on it and press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

If you want to find implementations of a symbol (like an interface or method that may be overridden) in the editor, press <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> on it.

Comment: It would be useful that this exists as in IntelliJ :)

Comment: ctrl + shift + t also lets you open a specific Type of a file. I know some people have written plugins that build a cache of symbols for source files that you have visited.

Comment: Regrettably, if the methods and variable names you are trying to find are inside of a jar file, you have no way to find them in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a Flash Builder-only thing, but <kbd>ctrl+o</kbd> will do the trick if you're just looking within the class you're in (which I realize is a variant of your specific question but is helpful and similar anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse allows you to search the project.  That's probably the closest to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at: Navigate > Open From Clipboard. 
Shortcut assigned in Neon for this: Ctrl+Shift+V.

Answer (score 0):

"Open element" is the closest I know, as it *lets you start typing and glob up classes, method names, variable names, etc*. as requested.

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+T pops up "Open type" for me. Do you mean CTRL-O / CTRL-F3 aka "Quick outline"?

Comment: I haven't used eclipse in a while, so it may have changed, but searching for "eclipse open element" I found [a](https://www.badprog.com/eclipse-tips-n-tricks-open-element) [few](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/64795/) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266862/most-useful-shortcut-in-eclipse-cdt) mentioning Ctrl+Shift+T. FWIW, I used Eclipse CDT mostly (not sure if it makes a difference).