# Eclipse - see which methods of one class are used in another?

Tags: java, eclipse

With Eclipse, given the following classes:

```
class Dao {
    public void one() {}
    public void two() {}
    public void three() {}
}

class ServiceA {
    Dao dao;
    public void a() {
        dao.one();
        dao.two();
    }
    public void b() {
        dao.one();
    }
}

class ServiceB {
    Dao dao;
    public void z() {
        dao.two();
        dao.three();
    }
}
```

... is it possible to see a list of all `Dao` methods referenced from `ServiceA`? I'm looking for one view that will show that `ServiceA` uses `one()` and `two()` (don't mind it if `one()` is listed twice).

I know how to see callers of one specific method. I really need a list of all methods referenced within a class. Think of legacy code orders of magnitude larger: dao and services that have tens (hundreds?) of methods. I don't feel like going through call hierarchy method by method.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839156/how-can-i-find-references-of-a-class-in-eclipse

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can click by right mouse button at Dao method and then click at 'Open Call Hierarchy Ctrl+Alt+H' and Eclipse will find for you all Dao method calls.

Comment: Thank you, but I really need a list. I don't feel like going through all methods one by one in legacy monster classes.

Comment: Yes, except for that I need it from the opposite side. See all methods called from Service, not all calls of Dao.conreteMethod().

Answer (score 5):

Konrad Garus Jun 30 '11 at 7:37 said in a comment:

> Yes, except for that I need it from the opposite side. See all
>   methods called from Service, not all calls of Dao.conreteMethod().

– 
I need to create a new answer because I'll use two pictures to illustrate my point. (Cannot use images in comments)

'Ctrl+Alt+H' brings up call hierarchy, as has been mentioned here by other people.

Then you need to click on these icons, depending on what you need:

[image: Show Callee Hierarchy]

And

[image: Show Caller Hierarchy]

**Edit**:

What about VonC's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685467/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-goto-function-name) (it's the one with the saw-tooth-rimmed screenshot image inside)?

Here I've used  CTRL-H to code-search for calls to Dao.one().

Result: In the search result view, there's another little icon "group by type).

[image: code search result]

Comment: Right, but it still acts on method, not class level. What I need is not methods called from my method, by all methods called from my *class*.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+Shift+G` to perform a search  which shows all the places where your method or selected class is being used.

Additionally, you can temporarily set all the `public` methods to `private` visibility and check the places where errors are popping up.

Comment: You have edited the question while this answer was being typed.

Comment: Reference search doesn't show method calls, does it? Changing access to private could do, but that's really a hack and a lot of work.

Comment: Nice! Ctrl+Shift+G does it at class level.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Code Coverage plugin/tool for this.

For example:

- Dependency Analyzer
  (http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/)
- Codecover
- UCDetector
- FindBugs
- PMD
- CodePro Analytics (free from Google)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on a method and select Open Call Hierarchy you all get the list of all the classes using the particular method.