# How do I get a list of Methods called from a Class in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I am using Eclipse IDE for my Java project. I need a list of methods which are being called from a particular class i.e. I need to see a list of all the methods which are being called from a class but not declared in that. I am looking for some option which might be there in Eclipse already. I am not willing to write a code for this (that will be my last choice).

Let me explain using this example -

```
public class ABC {

 public void methodA {
  System.out.println("In methodA");
  BCD bcd = new BCD();
  bcd.callMethodAA(); // defined in class BCD
 }

 public void methodB {
  System.out.println("In methodB");
  CDE cde = new CDE();
  cde.callMethodBB(); // defined in class CDE
 }
}
```

I want an option which will show me -
From Class ABC we are calling -
a) callMethodAA
b) callMethodBB

Comment: Do you want to know at which methods of a class was called by any other class during runtime?

Comment: Reading your question, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish... Are you trying to log the methods that are being called? Take a look at AOP approaches. Are you trying to follow the execution of a particular instance in real time? Use a debugger. Are you trying to know (statically) which methods are being called by other classes of your application and at what line of code? Take a look at the call hierarchy for that particular method.

Comment: Question edited. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Not quite... It is clear that you want a static option which lists method dependencies... Is your exact need something like "Given class `A` list all methods of other classes called in `A`"? If so, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530750/eclipse-see-which-methods-of-one-class-are-used-in-another

Comment: @Anthony Accioly: Call Hierarchy is the opposite direction. Get the calling methods. He likes to get the called methods. - See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to list only the method being used, there is no in-language way to achieve that. Though there might be some coverage tools which can handle this.

But If its about all the available methods, you can use reflection:

```
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("className");
    Method[] methodList = cls.getMethods();
```

Comment: You could find out when a method does get invoked using CGLIB though. Although I am unsure if the OP is asking for all methods in a class (whether declared or inherited from superclass) or if he wants to know when a method is called.

Comment: I just want to know - what all methods I am calling from my class which are declared in some other class. Also, I want to achieve this by using some option present in Eclipse e.g. as we see Outline to get the list of all members of a class.

Answer (score 3):

To find the methods that are called from a class (assuming programatically), I would use the [ASM bytecode analyzing/manipulation library](http://asm.ow2.org/). The below example is a `ClassVisitor` that prints all the methods called from a class.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassAdapter;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.InstructionAdapter;

public class MethodCallFinder extends ClassAdapter {

    private String name;

    public MethodCallFinder(ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
        super(classVisitor);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        this.name = name;
        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        return new MethodCallPrinter(super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions));
    }

    private class MethodCallPrinter extends InstructionAdapter {

        public MethodCallPrinter(MethodVisitor methodVisitor) {
            super(methodVisitor);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
            System.out.printf("Class %s calls method %s with descriptor %s from class %s%n", MethodCallFinder.this.name, name, desc, owner);
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a single method that invokes all the methods on your class. If you already have one of those even better. Take the Logo.java class from Junit as an example if I create this:

```
private void ExposeAllCalledMethods()
{
    Logo x = new Logo();
    x.loadImage("something");
    Graphics g;
    x.paint(g);     
}
```

Note I didn't need to call paintBackround() because paint() already calls it.

Then I can right-click in the method name ***ExposeAllCalledMethods*** and select Open ***Call Hierarchy***. Then in the call hierarchy window  click on the ***Callees*** button *(see the green arrow in the image)* and open all the gray hierarchy arrows as shown in the image below. A complete list of all methods called by the current class is shown.

<Shameless Plug> Now I wish I had shown how to do this in my [new Pluralsight Eclipse course.](http://goo.gl/x61qUz) </Shameless Plug>

[image: Hierarchy window showing all called methods].

Comment: That's interesting but still does not answer my query. Let me re-edit my question.

Comment: Yes, I realize it has two flaws, one is you have to add a tramp method, the other is it includes methods from the current class. The latter problem is mitigated a little by the fact that you can easily see the full class name, ie. junit.awtui.Logo to the right. I don't see a way around the former problem yet.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can do this by selecting (highlighting) the method in an editor pane, then constructing the Call Hierarchy (probably Ctrl-Alt-h).  You can then switch from "Show Caller Hierarchy" (default) to "Show Callee Hierarchy" using the toggle buttons in the top-right of the Call Hierarchy pane.  The one you want looks like sideways tree with children to the right, like o-[ not ]-o.

Answer (score 0):

If it is at runtime, you could use a [Dynamic Proxy](http://javahowto.blogspot.de/2011/12/java-dynamic-proxy-example.html).
The dynamic proxy is called before the method invocations of your class and you can log somewhere (to another class, or a file or whatever) which methods have been called.

Answer (score 0):

The answer dependents on the context:

If you like to have this for your code within your IDE: This depends on the IDE. In Eclipse, I believe, it is not possible. You can get the method which calls a given class (constructor of method) via "Open Call Hierarchy".

If you like to do it at runtime: This is solvable with AspectJ, see for example http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-thisJoinPoint.html (at the end there is a piece to get the caller of any method).