# See which methods of one class are used in another in IDEA

Tags: java, class, methods, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530750/eclipse-see-which-methods-of-one-class-are-used-in-another), but then with JetBrains Intellij IDEA 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform "Find Usages" search (Alt+F7) for the class (Dao), you can [click on search preferences button](http://screencast.com/t/02A7oGg3kV). There you can choose to find usages of the method

That should [do the trick](http://screencast.com/t/B1O3TsuxqsMD)